# Decrypting data with CCCryptor in Objective-C that was encrypted with CFB in Go

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, go, cryptography

I've been working on this for a long time, but am stuck.

I'm writing an iOS app that takes AES encrypted data form a Go server-side application and decrypts it. I'm using CCCryptor for the decryption on the iOS side. However, I cannot, for the life of me, get plaintext out. There is a working Java/Android implementation, and it decrypts fine on the Go side, so I'm pretty sure it's to do with my CCCryptor settings.

I'm actually getting a 0 success status on decryption, but taking the output and doing a NSString initWithBytes gives me a null string.

Note: I'm only writing the iOS side.

**Go code that encrypts:**

```
func encrypt(key, text []byte) []byte {

  block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  b := encodeBase64(text)
  ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(b))
  iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
  if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  cfb := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)

  cfb.XORKeyStream(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], []byte(b))

  return ciphertext
}
```

**Objective-C code that decrypts**

```
+ (NSData *)decrypt:(NSData*)data withPassword:(NSString*)password{


NSData * key = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

size_t dataLength   = [data length] - kCCBlockSizeAES128;
NSData *iv          = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, kCCBlockSizeAES128)];
NSData *encrypted   = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(kCCBlockSizeAES128, dataLength)];

//See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
//equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
//That's why we need to add the size of one block here
//    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
//    void *buffer = malloc(dataLength);
NSMutableData *ret = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128];

size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus status = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES,
                                 0x0000, // change to 0 solve the problem
                                 [key bytes],
                                 kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                 [iv bytes],
                                 [encrypted bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                 [ret mutableBytes], [ret length], /* output */
                                 &numBytesDecrypted
                                 );

NSLog(@"err: %d", status);
NSLog(@"dataLength: %d, num: %d", (int)dataLength, (int)numBytesDecrypted);
if (status == kCCSuccess) {
    //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
    return ret;
}

//    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
return nil;
}
```

Comment: Note: as soon as I saw that the data was being Base64 encoded prior to encryption red flags went off, that makes no sense and indicate someone without a good grounding in cryptographic usage hads created the code. In order to obtain security, not just cryptography, one needs a domain expert. Your security needs may vary.

Comment: 1. A CCCryptorStatus of 0 means little, certainly not that the decryption was successful or not. 2. Base64 encoding prior to encryption makes no sense in general, AES encryption is 8-bit data based. 3. it is unclear if any padding is being done on the Go side, it looks like it is xor'ing a stream, the iOS side is operating in CBC block mode without padding which is incorrect unless all data is a multiple of the block size. 4. Not knowing Go test data is going to be required: data in, iv, data out all in hex dumps as close to the encryption calls as possible.

Comment: 5. It looks like Go is creating a random iv and that iv must get to the decryption code somehow, many times it is prepended to the data. 6. Go is using CFB mode which is not supported my CCCrypt. In CCrypt the key size must be explicitly specified, it looks like GO is determining a key size based on the supplied key

Comment: The best bet is to use AES with a specified key size and keys that are exactly that size, CBC mode with a random iv that is prepended to the encrypted tex and PKCS#7 padding. Further, it the key is a password it should be converted to a proper key with PBKDF2 prior to use. This is a common and rather secure method. The nice thing about CCCrypt is that all parameters are explicitly specified and are all 8-byte data, it is completely clear what is happening. Wit Go it is going to take some documentation digging to understand what is being done "under the hood".

Comment: Are you sure the block size is 128? Also... if you don't get a good answer here, try asking on the CCCryptor GitHub Issue Tracker.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert AES has only one block size of 128-bits, there is no mention of Rijndael. There is a mismatch between Go CFB mode and CCCrypt default mode of CBC. The main issue is what Go is really doing, how the iv is being passed and how they are handling padding, probably none with CFB mode. Do you have a link to the "CCCryptor GitHub Issue Tracker", I don't see any issues?

Comment: @zaph CFB is a streaming mode of operation, it does't need padding.

Comment: @CGuess the IV is not saved in the Go code. The Go part and encryption scheme must be re-thought completely. There seems to be no integrity or authenticity for it either.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes I am aware CFB is a streaming mode and does not need padding and yet the OP is trying to use CBC mode which does on the iOS side. I am hedging my words because I am not willing to spend the time to dive into the Go documentation without even knowing if the OP is going to pursue the question. The usual outcome is that the OP will not be able to or will be unwilling to change the server side and will not believe that their scheme needs to be changed. I agree with your assessment in your comment to the OP.

Comment: @zaph, I'm definitely pursuing this and your method above seems like a great first step. I didn't realize CCCryptor doesn't support CFB mode. Is there a particular AES mode that is recommended over others? You mentioned CBC, that's the best way to go?

Comment: @CGuess Great! My recommendation is to use RNCryptor, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor), there is an [iOS](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) and a [Go](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-go) implementation available.

RNCryptor combines all the necessary cryptographic primitives for your needs including:

- AES-256 encryption (Advanced Encryption Standard)
- CBC mode (Cipher Block Chaining)
- Password stretching with PBKDF2 (Password Based Key Derivation Function 2)
- Password salting
- Random IV (Initialization Vector)
- Encrypt-then-hash HMAC (Authentication)

It has been extensively deployed and vetted.

It is all to easy to get cryptography wrong and using RNCryptor will avoid the potential pitfalls.

If I had the cryptographic needs you have I would use it.